# Expresiones regulares JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Alguien podría ayudarme en esta expresión regular, tiene que cumplir con esto
*Mínimo de 8 caracteres, al menos 1 alfabeto en mayúsculas, 1 alfabeto en minúsculas, 1 número y 1 carácter especial, no espacios en blanco*

Me funciona casi todo, pero lo que hace es que me acepta `Mexico2019` y no `Mexico.2019`

```
<form  name="pass" method="POST" action="change.php"  onsubmit="return validateF()">
      <div class="input-container">
        <i class="fa fa-user icon"></i>
        <input class="input-field" type="text" name="user" id="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["user"];?>" disabled>
      </div>
      <div class="input-container">
        <i class="fa fa-key icon"></i>
        <input class="input-field" type="password" placeholder="New Password" name="pw" id="pw" >
      </div>

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      <input type="submit" value="Update" style="background-color: blue; color: white">
  </div></form>
```

Script

```
 function validateP(cod){

        var re = /^[a-z\d\{punct}]{8,}$/i; 
        var nre = /^([A-Z]{8,}|[a-z]{8,}|[A-Za-z{punct}]{8,}[\d\{punct}]{8,}|[A-Z\d\{punct}]{8,}|[a-z\d\{punct}]{8,})$/; 
        return (re.test(cod) && !nre.test(cod));
      }

      function validateF(){

        var form = document.forms['pass'];
        var pw = form['pw'];
        var strError = '';
        var focusError = null

        if(!strError && !validateP(pw.value)){
          strError = 'Mínimo de 8 caracteres, al menos 1 alfabeto en mayúsculas, 1 alfabeto en minúsculas, 1 número y 1 carácter especial, no espacios en blanco:';
          focusError = pw;
        }

        if(strError){
          swal(strError);
          if(focusError!=null) focusError.focus();
        }
        return (''==strError);

  }
```

PHP

```
$usuario =$_SESSION['user'];
echo $pw = $_POST['pw'];
$consulta = "UPDATE admin SET pw='$pw' WHERE user = '$usuario';";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $consulta);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te anexo un ejemplo de una expresión regular con lo que pides, hice las pruebas llamando directamente a la función `validateP`:

```js
function validateP(cod){

        var nre = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&()\/*-`.#+,])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&()\/*-`.#+,]{8,}$/g;
        return (nre.test(cod));
      }

      function validateF(){

        var form = document.forms['pass'];
        var pw = form['pw'];
        var strError = '';
        var focusError = null

        if(!strError && !validateP(pw.value)){
          strError = 'Mínimo de 8 caracteres, al menos 1 alfabeto en mayúsculas, 1 alfabeto en minúsculas, 1 número y 1 carácter especial, no espacios en blanco:';
          focusError = pw;
        }

        if(strError){
          swal(strError);
          if(focusError!=null) focusError.focus();
        }
        return (''==strError);

  }
  
  console.log(validateP("mExico.2019"));//Correcto
  console.log(validateP("MEXICO.2019"));//Incorrecto - No minusc
  console.log(validateP("mexic.o2019"));//Incorrecto - No mayusc
  console.log(validateP("mexic.ooo"));//Incorrecto - No numeros
  console.log(validateP("mEx1c."));//Incorrecto - No 8 caracteres
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Si lo llamo así con el console.log().. si me funciona 
pero de la forma en la que yo la estoy haciendo sigue sin funcionar 
ya agregue mas parte del código de como lo mando, es para actualizar una  contraseña

Comment: mmm... Debiste de hacer eso desde un principio compañero, yo no sé usar PHP (de momento), debes colocar las etiquetas que correspondan a tu código, como solo colocaste Javascript se me hizo sencillo responder, te recomiendo colocar las otras etiquetas para que más gente pueda observar tu pregunta y te puedan ayudar, de momento solo dejaré mi respuesta ya que sirve de base a tu respuesta. Saludos compañero.

Comment: Muchas gracias :)